# how can I add date with an integer field

Tags: postgresql, datetime, postgresql-9.3

In PostgreSQL
In an application we get the information from members and the expiry date(timestamp) of their account is "the date of today + the period of time that their account type shows": for example today is 2020-01-06 and they choose gold account which is 9 month(I defined it integer) , so their expiry date should be: 2020-10-06 what is the best way for writing that code in short one ?

Comment: Is this what you want: `select current_date + interval '9' month`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following simple multiplication using `*`:

```
select the_date + interval '1 month' * your_integer_column from your_table;
```

See demonstration here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/66247/1/0

Comment: I really appreciate you , it is OK :)

Comment: excuse me is this line correct? when I run it in my code it would be in a loop:         val is selected from a table which is integer which shows the number of mounth                         update users set expiary_date= (select current_date +interval '1 month' * val where user_id=user_id_users);

Comment: the error is :   SQL statement "update users set expiary_date= (select current_date +interval '1 month' * val where  user_id=user_id_users)"
PL/pgSQL function acc_type_expiary() line 17 at SQL statement and this error is repeated a lot